# Can I upgrade from iOS 6.0.1 to iOS 8.1.1 directly?

Tags: itunes, ipad, software-update

I have an iPad 2 (Wi-Fi) which I want to update iOS 8, so I downloaded iOS 8.1.1 for iPad 2 Wi-Fi's IPSW.

I updated with iTunes on my PC but it says that it cannot update my iPad!
I want to install iOS 8.1.1 but current version on the iPad is 6.0.1.

Why can't I upgrade it?

Comment: Was the iPad previously jailbroken?

Comment: Is your iPad offering to download the update directly via Settings > General > Software Update?

Comment: either try getting the update from iTunes itself, or check with http://ipswdownloader.com that you got the right file. btw, I really hope you didn't pay money for that file - all Apple updates are **free**

Comment: The current version is actually 8.1.2 now. You mentioned though that you "bought" the iOS 8.1.1 IPSW. These updates are free from Apple. If you paid for it, you should immediately demand your money back. Chances are, if you were asked to pay for it, it is a corrupt image, a pre-jailbroken hack, a misstated blank file, or simply the wrong IPSW for your build of iPad.

Comment: Unless you go through some special process, Apple will only give you a download for the latest version of iOS 9 on my iPad 2 since iOS 10 won't run on it. Whether you go to version 8 or 9 though you're going to see a speed hit. It's fast enough as long as I don't do anything that uses too much RAM.

Answer (score 1):

The iPad 2 will run iOS 8.1.2. However, if the storage is full it will not be able to install the update.

Connect your iPad to your computer and open iTunes. Check the iPad's storage. If there is less than 5 GB free space, delete movies, music or larger apps until there is space (you can reinstall easily after the update).

From iTunes, click "Update". iTunes will download the proper update from Apple and do everything necessary.

If it still complains, do this:

While connected to iTunes, click "Backup". When it finishes, disconnect the iPad, open Settings, and choose "Erase all content". Plug it back into iTunes, update it, and choose "restore backup".